# Where is message bundle stored when application is running ( memory or disk )?

Tags: java, struts2, struts

I am using JAVA Struts2. I am reading the properties file using getText() of ActionSupport ( provided by struts2 ).

Comment: I would get it gets read into a hashmap of some sort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are stored as `java.util.ResourceBundle` instances in a static `ConcurrentMap` in the `LocalizedTextUtil` in the XWork core lib.

By default, ResourceBundles are cached in memory.

Answer (score 2):

By default, it's stored in memory.  But if you want to have the framework check your properties file for each lookup, you can do that to.  It's a nice thing for development.

You can configure such things in your `struts.properties` file.  The following is from the `struts-default.properties`, which serves as a commented boilerplate for such configuration.

```
### when set to true, Struts will act much more friendly for developers. This
### includes:
### - struts.i18n.reload = true
### - struts.configuration.xml.reload = true
### - raising various debug or ignorable problems to errors
###   For example: normally a request to foo.action?someUnknownField=true should
###                be ignored (given that any value can come from the web and it
###                should not be trusted). However, during development, it may be
###                useful to know when these errors are happening and be told of
###                them right away.
struts.devMode = false

### when set to true, resource bundles will be reloaded on _every_ request.
### this is good during development, but should never be used in production
struts.i18n.reload=false
```

Setting either of these two properties to `true` in your `WEB-INF/classes/struts.properties` file will make the framework load from the physcial properties file for each lookup.